# Subdomain Setup

Tags: templating, database, license

I am trying to create two subdomain names:

- townsville.example.com
- brisbane.example.com

All subdomains would share the same database. They would be tied to the Pro license on example.com.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

Do I have to copy index.php to each subdomain root folder?

Answer (score 3):

If you create your folder structure like this:

```
craft/
public_html/
----townsville.example.com/
--------index.php
--------.htaccess
----brisbane.example.com/
--------index.php
--------.htaccess
```

And set the `$craftPath` variable in each `index.php` like this:

```
$craftPath = '../../craft';
```

It should do what you're looking for.